# React API JSON - Hide Repeating Values

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, rest

I had look up for this question but i am so confused. I'm fetching some message data as JSON from my Django backend server. I want to show message sender's username on my React front end but messages are all together. So i don't want to display repeating usernames.

**My codes as below:**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function Messages(props) {
  
  const [messa, setMessa] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/messagesapi/",{
      method:'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
      }
    })
    .then( res => res.json())
    .then( resp => setMessa(resp))
    .catch( error => console.log(error))
  }, [])




  return <div className="message-body">
  
  <ul className="LastMessages">
  { messa.filter((messa) => messa).map(mess => 
      
      {
         return <div>
<li>
    <b className="sender">{mess.sender}</b> 
    </li>
         </div>
       })}
   
  </ul>

  </div>
  
  ;
}

export default Messages;
```

**My output like this:**

```
user1, user1, user2, user1, user3, user2, user4, user5, user1
```

But i don't want to this. I just want to like:

```
user1, user2, user3, user4, user5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Set`, it’s perfect for this use. You will pass it your array of senders and it will omit duplicates:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Check this out:

```
const [senders, setSenders] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const setOfSenders = new Set();
    messa.forEach((mess) => setOfSenders.add(mess.sender));
    setSenders(setOfSenders);
  }, [messa]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {senders && Array.from(senders).map((sender) => <p>{sender}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
```

When `messa` is populated from the fetch, `useEffect` runs and creates a `Set` of unique senders.  Then in the `return` you create an array from the set to map out the values as usual.  This doesn't cover all use cases but is one way to go about it.

Here is a working example: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-borg-m8dhv?file=/src/App.js:336-681)

Comment: Thx your comment but I'm pretty new at React so i couldn't understand how to use this function :(

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are my hero xD !